# Symfony parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in autoload.php

Tags: php, symfony

Catching an error with Symfony 3, php 7.1.2 just after installation:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in
>   Z:\home\symf.loc\www\try01\app\autoload.php on line 9

The file **autoload.php**:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/** @var ClassLoader $loader */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

return $loader;
```

Any ideas what to do ?

Comment: Are you sure that you've run the project with PHP 7? Did you run the built-in server or did you use another webserver?

Comment: What is your php version ? You need at least PHP 5.4.0

Comment: PHP version is not PHP7, run `php -v`

Comment: Create a file in your doc root that contains `<?php phpinfo(): ?>` and open it in your browser to check the php-version. You can actually have different versions in CLI and on the web server.